# Cant login with facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I use facebook sdk for login/register in my app. I use this code in **LoginActivity**.

```
private void tryLoginWithFacebook() {
    openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {                    
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        // my code -- don't call this method
                    }
                }).executeAsync();

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

But method **onCompleted(...)** don't call.

Almost the same code in **RegisterAcitvity**.

P.S. When I click on the button facebook-login that there is a window with login - I enter the data, then the dialogue with the load - and nothing happens. I also want to say that in the registration screen all works.

Comment: Does your code enter the _newMeRequest_ block?

Comment: Who worked, for the first time. I did not change the code, but this behavior is not stable for the application to be used by people.

Comment: Check below bartol's answer, you need to add onActivityResult  in your activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have onActivityResult overriden in your activities?

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: Strange. Now works. I have not changed my code. And it is not clear, since users can be a problem.

Comment: Facebook is sometimes tricky, I spent a long hours debugging stuff connected to it :)